# stop calculation after upload of data until run is clicked again

Tags: r, shiny

I have a problem with my shinyapp. I want to upload data for my calculations. When I do so the app automatically runs through the whole script the moment the upload is complete, so I implemented an action button. When I start the app and upload the data I have to click on the action button, the program executes and everything works fine. But when I start the app and click on the action Button first and then upload data, the program executes without having to click on the run button again. I made an example here. Because my actual app is ways bigger I need this feature that the programs is not executing automatically after uploading new data once the action button was clicked for the data I uploaded in the first place. I know that there is `isolate()` and I tried to implement it in every position possible but without any result. Can somebody help me out here? 
Here the code. with example data.

```
Mydata<-data.frame(A=1:1100,B=rnorm(1100, 50, 5))
write.csv(Mydata, file = "MyData.csv")
```

and the app:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('files1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv', 
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                         '.csv'), multiple = TRUE),
      tags$hr(),

      radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                   c(Comma=',',
                     Semicolon=';',
                     Tab='\t'),
                   ','),
      actionButton("go","run",class = "btn-primary"),br()
    ),
    mainPanel(tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", "
             #loadmessage {
                           position: fixed;
                           top: 95%;
                           left: 0px;
                           width: 100%;
                           padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
                           text-align: center;
                           font-weight: bold;
                           font-size: 100%;
                           color: #000000;
                           background-color: #CCFF66;
                           z-index: 105;
                           }
                           ")),
              conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",
                               tags$div("Loading...",id="loadmessage")),
      verbatimTextOutput('text1')

      )
      )
  )


server <- function(input, output) {

observeEvent(input$go,{
  mapz <- reactive({
    inFiles <- input$files1

    if (is.null(inFiles))
      return(NULL)
    Q <- read.csv(input$files1[[1, 'datapath']],sep=input$sep,dec="." )
    names(Q)<-c("A","B")
    Q<-Q[Q$A<1000,]
    nom<-seq(round(min(Q$A)),floor(max(Q$A)),by=1)
    counts<-matrix(NA,nrow=length(nom),ncol=length(input$files1[,1]))
    return(list(as.matrix(nom),counts))
  })
  output$text1 <-renderPrint(if(is.null(input$files1)==FALSE) as.data.frame(mapz()[[1]]))
})}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One very quick and effective way you can do this is to make that part of the UI unavailable until the file or files are uploaded. Basically make a `uiOutput()` call in place of the `actionButton()` call and move the `actionButton()` into a `renderUI()` function in server that has a conditional looking for a not NULL return for `mapz()`. The button isnt available to be pressed unless there is a non NULL return for `mapz()`. You should also move the reactive that creates `mapz()` outside of the `observeEvent()` so that it becomes usable to the app regardless of whether the button is pressed or not. Now as a caveat this never resets the button so as long as there is a file uploaded the button is pressable. It is functionally the same so the ! operator works like the ==FALSE conditional. Heres the code with the suggested changes :

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
 titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
 sidebarLayout(
 sidebarPanel(
  fileInput('files1', 'Choose CSV File',
            accept=c('text/csv', 
                     'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                     '.csv'), multiple = TRUE),
  tags$hr(),

  radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
               c(Comma=',',
                 Semicolon=';',
                 Tab='\t'),
               ','),
  uiOutput("runbutton"),br()
),
mainPanel(tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", "
         #loadmessage {
                       position: fixed;
                       top: 95%;
                       left: 0px;
                       width: 100%;
                       padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
                       text-align: center;
                       font-weight: bold;
                       font-size: 100%;
                       color: #000000;
                       background-color: #CCFF66;
                       z-index: 105;
                       }
                       ")),
          conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",
                           tags$div("Loading...",id="loadmessage")),
  verbatimTextOutput('text1')

  )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
output$runbutton <- renderUI({
    if(!is.null(mapz()){
    actionButton("go","run",class = "btn-primary")
    }
})
mapz <- reactive({
inFiles <- input$files1

if (is.null(inFiles))
  return(NULL)
Q <- read.csv(input$files1[[1, 'datapath']],sep=input$sep,dec="." )
names(Q)<-c("A","B")
Q<-Q[Q$A<1000,]
nom<-seq(round(min(Q$A)),floor(max(Q$A)),by=1)
counts<-matrix(NA,nrow=length(nom),ncol=length(input$files1[,1]))
return(list(as.matrix(nom),counts))
})
observeEvent(input$go,{

output$text1 <-renderPrint(if(is.null(mapz())==FALSE)  as.data.frame(mapz()[[1]]))
})}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: this is great many thanks! But with render ui the run button is not there when opening the app which in these case is no problem but could be in bigger implementations. Is there no way of using sth like isolate?

Comment: I've never used `isolate()` in the manner i think you're trying to. The way I handle buttons that may get clicked more than once but will only execute the action when a dependency is met is to set a reactive buttonstate variable and use that to control the buttons ability to cause an action. I'll add the code to the answer with comments.

Comment: despite that the function in your answer will execute after files are uploaded and only wait to show the result until the action button is pressed?! But I also want the execution to take place only when the action button is pressed again because my app takes a lot of time . So there might be another way?

Answer (score 0):

dont know why exactly, but this seems to work:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('files1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv', 
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                         '.csv'), multiple = TRUE),
      tags$hr(),

      radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                   c(Comma=',',
                     Semicolon=';',
                     Tab='\t'),
                   ','),
      actionButton("go","run",class = "btn-primary"),br()
    ),
    mainPanel(tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", "
                                   #loadmessage {
                                   position: fixed;
                                   top: 95%;
                                   left: 0px;
                                   width: 100%;
                                   padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
                                   text-align: center;
                                   font-weight: bold;
                                   font-size: 100%;
                                   color: #000000;
                                   background-color: #CCFF66;
                                   z-index: 105;
                                   }
                                   ")),
              conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",
                               tags$div("Loading...",id="loadmessage")),
              verbatimTextOutput('text1')

    )
    )
    )


server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$go,{
    mapz1 <- reactive({
      inFiles <- input$files1

      if (is.null(inFiles))
        return(NULL)
      Q <- read.csv(input$files1[[1, 'datapath']],sep=input$sep,dec="." )
      names(Q)<-c("A","B")
      Q<-Q[Q$A<1000,]
      nom<-seq(round(min(Q$A)),floor(max(Q$A)),by=1)
      counts<-matrix(NA,nrow=length(nom),ncol=length(input$files1[,1]))
      return(list(as.matrix(nom),counts))
    })
    mapz<-reactive({isolate(mapz1())})

    output$text1 <-renderPrint(as.data.frame(mapz()[[1]]))
  })}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```